# Excel number format damage

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, kendo-ui, export

When I doing export to excel with `kendo-ui` javascript or `EPPlus` library (C#)
original number format damages:

```
sheet.rows[i].cells[c].format = '_-* # ##0_р_._-;-* # ##0_р_._-;_-* "-"??_р_._-;_-@@_-';
```

Mask format in code:

```
_-* # ##0_р_._-;-* # ##0_р_._-;_-* "-"??_р_._-;_-@@_-
```

Mask format in result final excel file:

```
_-* #\ ##0_р_._-;-* #\ ##0_р_._-;_-* "-"??_р_._-;_-@_-
```

I tried masks without spaces - it works, but these formats not required for me.
What causes this behavior?

Comment: If you want a literal \ in your result, you need to use \\ in you assignment because \ is used as an escape character in javascript and C# strings.

Comment: I know, but I not want \ in my result, I can't understand why spaces replaced with \ in final mask, that damage format and number display

Answer (score 0):

I think in kendo-ui you need to escape the hash characters:

```
sheet.rows[i].cells[c].format = '_-* \\\\# \\\\#\\\\#0_р_._-;-* \\\\# \\\\#\\\\#0_р_._-;_-* "-"??_р_._-;_-@@_-';
```